# PHP framework for simple CRUD API and authentication

Tags: php, rest, authentication, crud

I am looking for a PHP framework for a simple CRUD API that will need some authentication. 
The sole purpose of this app is to be highly scalable.

The php API will be very simple CRUD Rest with mostly writes. This API will be used only in a iphone application where the iPhone App is sending user data every couple of milliseconds/seconds.

The way i see it

```
 Load Balancer -> PHP Framework (Horizontally Scalable) -> RabbitMQ Cluster -> Some Java Servers talking tp Hadoop/Cassandra -> Hadoop/Cassandra Cluster
```

So the Load balancer will pick which app server to send the data. PHP will get the data via a POST, do some authentication work..Maybe some validation, and then send the data/message to RabbitMQ, which will then talk to some Java server to do reads and writes. There may be Cache server in there too somewhere.

So i just need a simple PHP framework that Can do Rest/CRUD, simple authentication. probably a token in the post request and then can talk to a RabbitMQ server.

The PHP framework should probably be light. I have used Laravel in the past and i know it has a queue implementation, but i think it may be too slow for this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any framework can do Rest/CRUD (this will be your job to implement). For speed, take a look at Phalcon (http://phalconphp.com/)

Comment: I wrote something that may be useful, see this [blog](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/02/simple-php-rest-api-script-mysql/), but you will need to add your own auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With those requirements I suggest you to use a microframework because of the lightweight. I have running a project with **Slim microframework** with good accomplishments. There are many in the market so I let you choose. 
Look at:
http://xybu.me/a-comparison-of-php-micro-frameworks/